# Loss of Silverlight mouse up events after mouse capture?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, mouse

I created a very simple test control that has a `Rectangle` on a canvas (within other containers, but inconsequential).  The `Rectangle` has event handlers for mouse down, mouse move, and mouse up.  If I capture the mouse in the Rectangle's MouseLeftButtonDown event, I do not receive a corresponding MouseLeftButtonUp event.

Some code:

```
private void rect1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (_captured = CaptureMouse())
    {
        _offset = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(rect1), Canvas.GetTop(rect1));
        _origin = e.GetPosition(RootCanvas);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}


private void rect1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (_captured)
    {
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
        _captured = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I attached event handlers for the container elements as well, just to make sure one of them wasn't getting the mouse-up event somehow, but none of them were.  Is there an expectation of this in Silverlight that I haven't yet learned?

Comment: I noticed a similar problem in a WPF application I'm developing, but dismissed it as I was trying to capture the mouse when other mouse buttons were pressed. Having realised it didn't work for anything other than left button down I abandoned that approach & didn't investigate the problem any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are little confused about what is actually capturing the mouse events.

Consider when you do this:-

```
 if (_captured = CaptureMouse())
```

what object is the `CaptureMouse` actually being called against?

Answer: The user control for which your code is the code-behind. Had you wanted the rectangle to capture the mouse you would do:-

```
 if (_captured = rect1.CaptureMouse())
```

Comment: Not so much confused as not paying attention.  This is my facepalm moment of the day.  Thank you for pointing out what should have been obvious.

Answer (score 1):

CaptureMouse(); from mouseDown Event and then try.